# SDWebImage on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, sdwebimage

I followed the following tutorial http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.it/search?q=sdwebimage to add lazy image loading to my project.

I am using xCode 5.0.

In my project there is the "SDWebImage-3.3.framework" and in the build phases -> link binary... there are these 5 entries:
MapKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
UIKit.framework
Foundation.framework

In the ViewController.m file when I try to #import the SDWebImage I can only use this entry

## import "SDWebImage-3.3.framework"

and not the entry suggested by the tutorial

## import < SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

When I compile the project I get the following errors:

[image]

Do I have to do something else before I can use the framework?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JMImageCache. Doesn't have a lot of features, but works fine for what you intent to do, and it is superSimple to put into your project.

https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache